# External keyboard not working fine with laptop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, firebug

I plugged in external keyboard with my laptop so it keeps popping up inspect element and plus windows behaves in a strange way. When I unplugged the keyboard all work fine. Now, I want to work with external keyboard so, which setting can solve my problem. Heap of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely answer: buy a new keyboard.

But before you do that, plug the keyboard into a different computer and see if the issue is present there. If it is, then the keyboard is toast (unless you feel like disassembling it and cleaning it, which might work. It is a matter of how attached you are to the keyboard in question)

This can happen if you spill something on/in the keyboard, causing the PCB to corrode, or the keys to stick.